# JQGrid setGridParam URL not working in firebox, the same code in working chrome, but its not not working firebox,

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Here is my code , the same code hitting the URL in chrome, **setGridParam** function is not working properly, but its not working in firebox, i tried as much as possible ways, please help me to out.

```
              Cur_Status = $("#ddlStatus option:selected").val();    
               var FromDate = $("#txtFromDate").attr("value");
               var ToDate = $("#txtToDate").attr("value");
               var pieces = FromDate.split('/');
               pieces.reverse();
               FromDate = pieces.join('-');
               var pieces = ToDate.split('/');
               pieces.reverse();
               ToDate = pieces.join('-');
               if (new Date(FromDate) > new Date(ToDate)) {
                   alert("Please select ToDate greater than FromDate.");
                   return false;
               }
               var MyCall = 0;
               var check = document.getElementById("ChkMycall").checked;
               if (check) {
                   MyCall = 1;
             }
               else {
                   MyCall = 0;
               }
               var CheckStatus = 
               $('input:radio[name=rbt_Type]:checked').val();
               FromDate = $("#txtFromDate").attr("value");
               ToDate = $("#txtToDate").attr("value");
               var today = new Date();
               var dd = today.getDate();
               var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
               var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
               if (dd < 10) {
                   dd = '0' + dd
               }
               if (mm < 10) {
                   mm = '0' + mm
               }
               var today = mm + '/' + yyyy;
               var Cur_Date = today;                 
                 var qryStr = CheckStatus + "^" + FromDate + "^" + ToDate + "^" + MyCall;
                  $("#tblCallStatus").jqGrid("clearGridData");
               $("#tblCallStatus").setGridParam({ url: "../Handlers/CallStatusHandler.ashx? Mode=Load & iStatus=" + Cur_Status + "&Date=" + Cur_Date + "& QryString=" + qryStr, datatype: "json" });
               $("#tblCallStatus").trigger('reloadGrid');
```

this the code i am using, to hit the URL, through the javascript i try to load the JQGrid.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? What you mean - does not wor? What is happen? Please, check your url. As hint try to use a very simple url like `url: 'myurl.html'` and see if it works. If this is true, then check how is your url builded.

Comment: thanks  for your response, this same code is working in Chrome but its not working mozilla firebox.

Answer (score 0):

The URL, which you set contains a lot of spaces, which should be not used. Try to replace

```
url: "../Handlers/CallStatusHandler.ashx? Mode=Load & iStatus=" + Cur_Status + "&Date=" + Cur_Date + "& QryString=" + qryStr
```

to

```
url: "../Handlers/CallStatusHandler.ashx?Mode=Load&iStatus=" + Cur_Status + "&Date=" + Cur_Date + "&QryString=" + qryStr
```